# Why am I receiving "unexpected end of input" upon updating this file?

Tags: javascript

Upon fixing the bug with this script - [Why am I receiving a "Unexpected token )" error when my code seems perfectly fine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54725189/why-am-i-receiving-a-unexpected-token-error-when-my-code-seems-perfectly-fin)

I now receive a new error "unexpected end of input" on line 1272

```
    String.prototype.qis_separator = function(sr) {

    if (sr == 'none') return this;
    else { var s = ((sr == 'comma')? ',':' '); }
    var str = this.split('.');
    if (str[0].length >= 4) {
        str[0] = str[0].replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1'+s);
    }
    return str.join('.');
}
```

Script.js [full code] - https://jsfiddle.net/cx2z8m4r/

Why am I receiving this new error when this wasn't the case before I fixed the previous error?

Comment: The only warnings JSHint gives about this code are a missing semi-colon at the very end and `s` is used out of scope.  The described error isn't found in this code.  (And "line 1272" implies that there may be more code involved...)

Comment: Please take your time to recreate a minimum replicable environment so we can actually be contextualised and help out.

Comment: The full code is here - https://jsfiddle.net/cx2z8m4r/

Answer (score 0):

You're not closing the `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` on line 1124.

Add `});` to the end of your file.

Comment: I noticed this but fixing this error creates more errors and the slider doesn't work.

Comment: Even though your code may have other problems does this answer your question? There isn't anything about a slider in this question.